Enchantments missing in ForgeRegistries
Could Mojang or Forge rename the registry ENCHANTMENTS to something else? Because I can’t find it.
I am currently trying to make a mod for minecraft 1.21, that raises the max level of every enchantment to 255 (or higher, if it will let me). So I tried the make the mod go through the registry ForgeRegistries.ENCHANTMENTS, only to find out, that a registry like this doesn't exist in either ForgeRegistries or BuiltInRegistries, nor could I find the answer anywhere on the internet, so if anybody knows, then please help.
My code currently looks like this:
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraft.world.item.enchantment.Enchantment;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

@Mod("unlimitedenchants")
public class UncappedEnchantments {
    public UncappedEnchantments() {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onCommonSetup(FMLCommonSetupEvent event) {
        uncapAllEnchantments();
    }

    private void uncapAllEnchantments() {
        for (Enchantment enchantment : ForgeRegistries.ENCHANTMENTS) {
            try {
                Field maxLevelField = Enchantment.class.getDeclaredField("maxLevel");
                maxLevelField.setAccessible(true); // Allows you to access private fields
                maxLevelField.set(enchantment, 255);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error uncapping enchantment: ");
            }
        }
    }
}

